# How do I remove the (Default) REG_SZ?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, context-menu, string

How do I remove the **(Default)** `REG_SZ` from a key and replace it with a `REG_EXPAND_SZ` value with the same name?

The `REG_SZ` type doesn't suit my purposes, but the command expects the 1st (or ***only*** value to be the one used for its purposes).

Context menu `Delete` shows a Confirm dialog and then reports ***"Unable to delete all the specified values"***

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done in `regedit.exe`, but it is possible with **PowerShell** or a `.reg` file.

To create a new key, use `New-Item`:

```
New-Item 'HKCU:\SoftWare\MyKey' -Value '%UserProfile%' -Type ExpandString
```

To modify an existing key, use `Set-ItemProperty`:

```
Set-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\SoftWare\MyKey' -Name '(Default)' -Value '%Windir%' -Type ExpandString
```

And a `.reg` file looks like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MyKey]
@=hex(2):25,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,69,00,72,00,25,00,00,00
```

To obtain the desired byte sequence, create a `REG_EXPAAND_SZ` value under any key, export, and copy the bytes to the `@=` line.